# OpenGL with winform C++/CLR

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, c++-cli

Is it possible to call the function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMotionFunc(mouseMovement); //check for mousemovement
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

inside a button click event ? where display,keyboard etc are different functions

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
          main(); -------(Not sure of syntax)
    }
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to call `main` inside another function.

Comment: You'll need to move the content of your main function into a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just had to create a class the call the function as an object in the button click event and it was working as I wanted. Thanks for the help anyways

**Just declared a class in the header file**

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    int main(int argc, char **argv);

};
```

**Defined the main function in the .cpp as**

```
 foo::foo()
    {
    }


    foo::~foo()
    {
    }

     - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    ------Other functions here-----
     - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    //main function    
    int foo::main(int argc, char **argv) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
        glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
        -------------
        ----------
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
}
```

**And finally call it in the button click event**

```
private: System::Void btn_Load_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)  
{

    foo Objct;
    int Arg1;
    char** Arg2;
    int functn = Objct.main(Arg1, Arg2);
}
```